# Earth electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, earth, information

Nowadays an unlimited amount of information can be transferred around the planet using wireless methods.
Is that possible to transfer the information using natural electromagnetic field such as Earth magnetosphere?
What else natural fields are able to carry clusters of information besides artificially generated waves?

Comment: What type of information do you mean?  Certainly, the natural electromagnetic field carries information; for example, it fluctuates due to the solar wind.  Or do you mean specifically information generated by humans?

Answer (score 1):

**No**
Basically earths magnetic field is not a constant magnetic field like a bar magnet. It is more over dynamo effect. As like, earths molten core is moving and producing magnetic field. To any sorts of communication, we require fixed frequency of signal. Which will not be the case if you consider this dynamic system.
Earth magnetic field is constantly changing in magnitude and the direction also varies time to time. If you read closely, our magnetic poles are shifting from their current position.
The third major issue our communication channel will face is constant impact of solar winds. Which will be very dangerous and completely alter our signal.
Solar winds are known as coronal mass ejections. They are a burst of high energetic charged ions. Which heavily affect our communication channels.

Comment: Hi Adwait, welcome to the site.  A correction: Solar winds are not known as coronal mass ejections.  Those are two distinct phenomena of solar physics.  Coronal mass ejections might be associated with periods of enhanced solar wind, which may in turn disrupt communication on Earth when it arrives, but the coronal mass ejections do not directly affect the Earth.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation and a correction to the Coronal mass ejections that follow. It is very interesting that to establish networks of data exchange humanity has chosen the way of generating powerful signals to carry data on the planet. While  "Earth magnetic field is constantly changing in magnitude and the direction also varies time to time," the artificially generated waves that carry the information also may be affected by a range of factors at a certain rate. Thus, maybe natural electromagnetic fields that already exist can be used without causing harm to the environment and save$